# managing a resource in webapplication's multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, web-applications

Could you please suggest if the below flow is thread safe -

Web application gets a request -> fetch the data from request -> process it -> write to a temp file -> temp file goes to batch process which inserts data in db.

My concern is when multiple request would be hitting at same time, writing on the temp file would be thread safe or not.

I would be more than happy for any suggestion.

P.S. - The web application is not inserting data itself but the batch process is because the interface of batch process with db is well proven and tested (kinda legacy application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java web application servers queue up incoming requests and create a pool of worker threads to process them.  The app server assigns a thread from the pool to process the request at the head of queue, so the code used to process that request appears to be single-threaded from its point of view.

But the server itself is multi-threaded, because it uses a pool of threads.  Data or files that are shared by different threads are not thread-safe.  So you'll have to synchronize the section of the code that deals with writing to the file or lock it during the write operation.

If the temp files are not shared, then you don't a problem.  Do you create a file for each request?

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that your temp files have unique names, and each request creates it's own temp file, then I'd say it was threadsafe ( assuming of course that the processing within the servlet is also threadsafe. )

Answer (score 1):

If you use a synchronized method to write to the temp file if it is the same file in every request. It is pretty similar to write thread safe to a socket.